# Passing parameters using action tag in HTML

Tags: python, html, django, web, tornado

I'm working with Tornado (python), and my handlers are in this format.

```
class Application(tornado.web.Application):
    def __init__(self):
        handlers = [
            url(r'/', MainHandler, name="main_handler"),
            url(r'/user', UserHandler, name="user_handler"),
            url(r'/users', UserListHandler, name="user_list_handler"),
            url(r'/profile/(?P<username>\w+)', UserProfileHandler, name="user_profile_handler"),    
        ]
        settings = dict(
            template_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), "templates"),
            static_path = os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__),"static"),
            debug = True)
        self.db = client['user_db']
        super().__init__(handlers, **settings)
```

My HTML code on the landing page is

```
<h1>INFO DB</h1>
    <p>Search via username...</p>
    <form method="get" action="{% url 'user_profile_handler' find_username %}">
        <p>Enter Username<br>
        <input rows=1 cols=20 name="find_username"></p>
        <input type="submit">
    </form>
    <br>
```

Now my aim is when I click on the submit button,
I'm redirected to the page '/profile/{username}
Eg: if the username in the search bar is 'abcd', I should be redirected to /profile/abcd on pressing submit.
What to put in the action attribute of the form tag in HTML?

Answer (score 0):

Well django's Jinja tags like {% url %} are estimated on get so you'd have to actually pass find_username to context which you can't with these scheme because you're obtaining it after the page is loaded. To achieve what you're trying to do is to make a view that handles such situation. In pseudo code it would look like this

```
def view(request):

    form = username_form()

    if request.method == "POST":
        form = username_form(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            user = get_object_or_404(User, username=form.cleaned_data['username'])
            return redirect('profile', user.id)

    return render(request, ...., {'form': form})
```